# Python/Gspread How can I add column names while creating a worksheet?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

```
#For creating a new-sheet
sheets.add_worksheet(title=sheetName, rows=df.shape[0], cols=df.shape[1])

#For appending
values = df.values.tolist()
sheets.values_append(sheetName, {'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, {'values': values})
```

> It creates a new worksheet but there are no column names in it only the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
values = df.values.tolist()
```

#### To:

```
values = [df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
```

- By this, `values` has the data including the header row.

Comment: @ Tanaike 
Would you help me out with this too? 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544103/how-can-we-store-a-json-credential-to-env-variable-in-python]

Comment: @Subham I would like to check it. When I could correctly understand your new question and I got the answer, I would like to answer it.

Comment: Okay no problem.